# Getting height of LabelFrame in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a label frame, with the following specifications, I have not specified a height so that it could fit the contents it contains. Using winfo_height() returns 1 but this is not the actual height of the frame, how do I get the actual height?

I want to place a second frame beneath it with 5 pixel gap, therefore I want the height of the first frame.

```
frame1=LabelFrame(root,text="Pre Processing");
frame1.pack(expand="no",side="left",anchor=NW);
frame1.place(width=400)
left = Label(frame1)
left.pack(side="top")
R1=Radiobutton(frame1, other options)
R1.pack(anchor=NW);
R2=Radiobutton(frame1, other options)
R2.pack(anchor=NW);
R3=Radiobutton(frame1,other options)
R3.pack(anchor=NW);
#this line prints 1
print frame1.winfo_height()
```